# Is a multilayer perceptron a recursive function?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, multilayer-perceptrons, function-approximation

I read somewhere that a *multilayer perceptron* is a recursive function in its forward propagation phase. I am not sure, what is the recursive part? For me, I would see an MLP as a chained function. So, it would nice anyone could relate an MLP to a recursive function.

Comment: Are you sure the source was not referring to "recurrent neural networks"? Without having a link to the specific resource, it's difficult to answer this question, although both of the interpretations below look plausible to me.

Answer (score 5):

Inherently, no. The MLP is just a data structure. It represents a function, but a standard MLP is just representing an input-output mapping, and there's no recursive structure to it.

On the other hand, possibly your source is referring to the common *algorithms* that operate over MLPs, specifically forward propagation for prediction and back propagation for training. Both of these algorithms are easy to think about recursively, with each node performing a sort of recursive call with its children or parents as the target, and some useful information about activations or errors attached. I actually encourage my students to implement it recursively for this reason, even though it's probably not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can define plenty of things we don't generally need to regard as recursive as so. An MLP is just a series of functions applied to its input. This can be loosely formulated as

$$ o_n = f(o_{n-1})$$

Where $o_n$ is the output of layer $n$.

But this clearly doesn't reveal, much does it?